# How to drop a message in rabbitMQ?

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, ttl

Is there a way to drop a message on queue? 
I receive my packet header and check some pattern on that, when that pattern fails I want to drop it. Is there a way for that? How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In rabbitMQ, messages are published on exchanges, and delivered to queues. You can configure a exchange that discards messages that fits some header patterns. [Headers exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240290/how-do-i-implement-headers-exchange-in-rabbitmq-using-java). Or you can list a queue and ack a message that fits your pattern, without taking any further action, that is equivalent to drop message.

Comment: Packets that are not acknowledged are dropped? Is that what you say? Aren't they redelivered?

Comment: No, acknowledged packets are dropped from rabbit. Rejected packets are redelivered. If you want to drop a packet, simply send an ACK for it.

Comment: So non-matching patterns should be acked to get dropped? I think I'm a little on the dark side.

Comment: That's the idea. If you process headers on the queue side, ack those that you want to drop.

Comment: I've looked into our code and I've seen that we use nack with requeue=false for dropping packets, instead of ack'ing them, so I think that my first answer can be improved

Comment: nack a package to drop it is more sensible now, thanks for your help. ;-)